# F2 or F7 not functioning for the BIOS Setup and Boot Options, does not proceed to booting the OS.

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, motherboard, bios

I have a Clevo H251HPN laptop and I'm having a problem with my mainboard (as it seems).
When I turn on the laptop, it shows me the first screen, like always, which has the options F2 and F7 but then nothing else happens, plus when I'm trying to select one of these options, it seems that the option I pressed the button for gets highlighted but it doesn't do anything.

Any opinions?

I also found a manual for the laptop, but haven't found something useful or at least I don't know if I'm missing something.
http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/notebook/clevo/clevo_w251h...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mobo's I've used you have to press F5 repeatedly till it comes up with the OS boot option, then from there you press F8 to switch across to the advanced boot menu.

It can be slightly confusing when F8 is also the BIOS boot menu but it is F8. So press F8 a lot until you can choose which drive to boot from, then get ready to whack F8 a lot immediately after you choose and you'll get the Windows boot menu with safe mode etc etc.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: What I see when I turn on the laptop is this screen.

http://prntscr.com/e4bonx

And then nothing. No response from the motherboard and no OS loading. I've tried all of those keys/key combinations but still no response, except one time that I was spamming some known keys, such as Esc, Tab, Del, F8, and it proceeded to another screen trying to enter the setup, but then it froze again and I never saw this screen again.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, can you check with these few steps and revert me with the same?

1. Did you try F1 during boot? Some boards let you in this way.
2. Did you check with the keyboard, is it working or not? It happens sometimes!
3. Another trick: keep a key depressed while boot and you will get a keyboard error and go directly to bios.
4. Or, looked at all the keys at your keyboard, if any one of them was stuck down. Pulled it up, and no more problems.

Comment: Already tried all those things (after doing a bit research), that's why I believe it's an issue from the motherboard.